# Layout management using object oriented concept

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to use the Object-oriented concept to divide the UI into four sections(layout) with different sizes. So, each section contains different items(Plot, camera frame, Image, and label)

[screen layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ268.jpg)

I have a GUI class:

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Hello World")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False) # Don't resize UI
        self.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 500))   # Size of UI
```

What is the solution to implement that?
I believe I should have a Layout class and the object of this should change its charachteristic.

```
class layout(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Questions asking about a "best" solution are opinionated and are discouraged on StackOverflow.